# How to test uncaught/unhandled exceptions in behave?

Tags: python-2.7, testing, exception, python-behave

When an exception is raised in the application that is not accounted for (an uncaught/unhandled exception), it should be logged. I would like to test this behaviour in behave.

The logging is there to detect unhandled exceptions so developers can implement handling for these exceptions or fix them if needed.

In order to test this, I think I have to let the code under test raise an exception. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to do that without hard-coding the exception-raising in the production code. This is something I like to avoid as I do not think this test-code belongs in production.

While unit-testing I can easily mock a function to raise the exception. In behave I cannot do this as the application is started in another process.

How can I cause an exception to be raised in behave testing, so it looks as if the production code has caused it, without hard-coding the exception in the production code?

Answer (score 0):

Regadless to framework/programming language *exception* is a state when something went wrong. This issue has to be handled somehow by the application, that's why a good programmer will write exception handling code in places where it needed at most.

*Exception handling* can be everything. In your case you want to test that exception is logged. Therefore I see the an easy test sequence here:

1. Execute the code/sequence of actions which will rase the exception
2. Verify that log file has an entry related to the exception raised in previous step with help of your test automation framework.

Comment: You're missing an essential point. There is no code that raises an exception on purpose. If an exception is accidentally raised, it should be logged so it can be handled later.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your expected behavior for the production code?

- If your answer is "it should handle all exceptions gracefully" you're going to have a bad time (as in most cases with ultimate expressions like "all"), because you can't really list all scenarios.
- If you have a specific scenario, you can easily code that into a testcase.

Something along the line (yes, it's ridiculously simple):

```
Given my invalid input
When I perform the tested operation
Then the result should be the expected output (instead of some unhandled exception)
```

Based on your first sentence, your requirement looks more like the first one ("catch-all") and you do indeed want to "reach behind the code".
You also write that "In behave I cannot do this as the application is started in another process." - this need not necessarily be that way. Even if the application is started in another process for the other tests (there can be a number of reasons to do so), it's perfectly valid to create behave tests that use classes/methods of the production code directly from the step definitions so you can apply mocking techniques. If you don't have suitable classes to be able to cover your scenario, you'll need some refactoring of course.

I'd like to stress, that this isn't just a neat trick that you can do, it's about the key concept of the test pyramid. When you're starting a complete application, you're doing integration testing (complete with file-system, db and UI usage). When you're targeting classes/methods isolated from the whole application, you're doing unit testing. And you can do either of them from both "unittest" and "behave" type of tests... And when you're using all integration tests, the base of your testing pyramid will be missing.